# Is filter_var a good way to go?

Tags: php, security

Is `filter_var` any good for filtering data? What kind of bad data will it filter? I do use `mysql_real_escape_string` but I wonder if adding `filter_var` will help?

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted

Comment: You should better try to understand what XSS and SQL injections are and why they are possible instead of asking for a miracle function to prevent them.

Comment: Will help what? What are you trying to do that you hope filter_var will accomplish?

Comment: downvoted because question is really vague. manipulating data is different for every kind of need. since you mention mysql_real_escape_string most people will assume you want filter_var in lieu of mysql_real_escape_string but at the same time you mention you also will be using that... filter_var is used for basic input sanitization/validation. http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.filter.php. as you will see from the manual, there's nothing specific for databases, only data types.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

To defend from SQL injection use prepared statements if possible. If not, use mysql_real_escape_string for strings, (int) casting or intval() for integers, (float) or floatval() for floats and addcslashes($input, '%_') for strings to be used inside LIKE statements. Things get even more complicated when trying to escape strings to be used inside RLIKE statements.

For filtering HTML content, the best would be strip_tags (without passing $allowable_tags), but... you may not like/want it, in which case the most affordable solution is:

```
$escaped = htmlspecialchars($input, ENT_QUOTES, $your_charset);
```

A more reliable solution would be to use a library like [HTML Purifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/)

Filter functions are OK, but some of them are more validators than filters. Depending on your needs you may find some of them useful.

Comment: htmlspecialchars() is the right thing to do for outputting text to HTML. strip_tags() would lose content if you wanted to use the legitimate ‘<’ character in text, and wouldn't display ‘&’ properly.

Answer (score 19):

You adjust `filter_var` by using it with the [`FILTER_*` constants](http://www.php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.php). It sounds like you're looking for [sanitisation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.sanitize.php) of data (actually adjusting the data to make it safe*) rather than [validation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.validate.php) (checking the data is safe).

Different filters can help with different tasks. While `mysql_real_escape_string` is ok for sanitising data to prevent SQL injection it's no good for outputting data that may contain HTML. Here's a couple of filter's I'd use for everyday tasks:

- `FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS` - useful for displaying (not removing) HTML code, preventing XSS attacks and converting symbols to HTML entities.
- `FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING` with the `STRIP_LOW/HIGH` flags - actually removes HTML (see `strip_tags`).
- `FILTER_SANITIZE_URL` - makes URLs safe*.
- `FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL` - makes email addresses safe, although I'd prefer to use it's validation cousin before storing the address.

> * I use safe loosely, I'm of the opinion that you can never be too sure.

Answer (score 2):

It all depends on what you mean by a valid url or a valid email.

For example `a@b-.c` - well, you could filter top level domains to exclude `.c` but the list of top level domains is not constant. Moreover all the characters are valid. Even though this looks weird and is almost certainly not valid, many regex filters will validate it too.

With the email `a@b-.c` or url `http://.` if displayed or used in links they will do no harm, even if they go nowhere.

I think part of the issue is the question of how loose do you want your filters. If the big concern is **XSS** or **SQL injection** or otherwise preventing dangerous input, whether or not the value is usable may be irrelevant, so this sort of filter may do the trick.

If you want to make sure the value is not just safe but also usable, that's a trickier beast.

Answer (score 1):

It really depends what you're trying to do, I can't really answer without knowing specifics. The possible filters and their effects are listed here: [Types of filters](http://php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.php)

Comment: Basically to filter and validate any xss or mysql exploits coming from user input.

Comment: There are too many ways (http://ha.ckers.org/xss.html) of XSS and SQL injections. It all depends on your application how it processed the user data.

Answer (score -5):

Just based on some minor testing, I've come to the conclusion that `filter_var`'s constants are not trustworthy.

For example:

```
filter_var('a@b-.c', FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL); // valid
filter_var('http://.', FILTER_VALIDATE_URL); // valid
filter_var('a@b-.c', FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL); // a@b-.c
filter_var('http://.', FILTER_SANITIZE_URL); // http://.
```

These are clearly invalid values, but pass `filter_var`'s constants. Do not trust `filter_var`.

Comment: Sanitising is not the same as validating though.

Comment: @Mathew, you're correct but I'm not sure what that has to do with the problems with `filter_var` I pointed out. It will neither correctly filter nor correctly sanitize the inputs I provided.

Comment: As far as I can see in http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc822 the email address are correctly formulated. In particular, `c` might be registered as a new TLD, and `b-` a domain therein (`-` is a valid character). I see no problems there. Is not `!def!xyz%abc+tag@[127.0.0.1]` a valid address? (I'll spare you wondering - it is.)

I didn't quickly turn up any examples of the domain name, though I can tell you that `dig .` gives a reasonable response, and `stackoverflow.com.` returns the same ip as `stackoverflow.com` (yes, trailing dot on first url). I agree with `filter_var` and PHP in this.